# How can I apply a CSS stylesheet to all page views in XULRunner

Tags: css, linux, firefox, xulrunner

I am trying to develop a display device (expected to be installed in public transports) which is able to show a (more or less fixed) web page in a chromeless embedded browser on a *Linux* platform (I am currently using *Archlinux*).

After a lot of tries with *Mozilla Firefox*, I am now focusing on the use of a small [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner) application using the following very simple **xul** document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="main" title="EPL Browser" width="1920" height="1080" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
 <browser type="content" src="http://www.example.org//" flex="1"/>
</window>
```

This works nearly as expected, but now I also want to apply to this page (whatever web page I choose) a CSS rule for removing unwanted scrollbars, like the following:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I was using *Mozilla Firefox*, this was very simple, I just needed to put it in a **chrome/userContent.css** file inside the *Firefox* profile.

But now I would like to know:

- Is there any mean to include my **userContent.css** file in my **xul** document in order to have it working the same way as in *Firefox*?
- If not, is there another way to apply this same CSS rule (and possibly others) to the page that I defined in the **xul** "browser" tag? For example by some other tags directly included in the **xul** document?

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the `userContent.css` file is in the `nsLayoutStyleSheetCache.cpp` file https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/nsLayoutStylesheetCache.cpp#314-341

Which looks like it is not Firefox specific, the app needs to not be safe mode, and there needs to be a profile used, otherwise I think you should be able to use this files.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you very well…
Are you telling me that I could actually set it in a Firefox profile (meaning, on Linux, in `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox...` directory) the same way as if I had used Firefox directly?

Comment: Ok, this seems to work.

The key is finding where is the XULRunner profile actually located.


I found that the actual place is specified into the `application.ini` XULRunner starting file, into the `[App]` section and under the `Profile` key, with (on Linux) a dot added on the front of the name if there is no one.


So if you write `Profile=xul_custom`, the profile will go into `$HOME/.xul_custom`.


If the Profile key is missing, the `Vendor` and `Name` keys are used.


So if `Vendor=mozilla` and `Name=firefox`, it will actually go into `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox`...